# Twitter Bootstrap Navbar Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently working on my first website for a local business and I'm having an issue with the navbar when viewed on movile devices. If the device is unable to display the entire navbar when you scroll to the right it shows an empty space. I'm not sure what is causing the issue, could someone please point me in the right direction?

Here's the site URL - www.riksystems.com/index.html

Thanks.

Comment: Try to use bootstrap-responsive styles.

Comment: You can duplicate this effect by resizing a desktop browser window to a width below about 1000px. Which is useful, because you have access to Firebug or an element inspector on the desktop. I've seen this sort of thing happen before with repeating backgrounds of unspecified width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a fixed layout and not a responsive one. Check directly from the getbootstrap how to create a responsive layout and check the code for a responsive navbar so when it is viewed on smaller resolutions the menu will colapse and show a button that you can click on to see the full menu.
Click [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navbar).

and scroll down for the responsive navbar.

Comment: Thanks for this I'll have a look at implementing a responsive navbar.